# Android Live Wallpaper touch event triggers when tapping an app icon

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am building a live wallpaper, and I noticed that the onTouchEvent method of the wallpaper service engine gets called when I tap on an app icon on the home screen. How do I filter out the taps that aren't directly onto the wallpaper? Thanks.

Edit: I don't know if you actually read that proposed duplicate, but it doesn't have to do with what I am asking. Please pay more attention.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Live Wallpaper touch events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006916/android-live-wallpaper-touch-events)

Comment: Looks like there isn't much you can do if using the onTouchEvent. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298458/android-live-wallpaper-touch-event-hierarchy